# Remapping d in vim to delete to null-buffer

Tags: vim

I would like to remap d in normal mode to "_d so that it doesn't overwrite my yank buffer. I tried using

```
:nmap d "_d
```

but after doing that if I hit d my vim just dies and I can't seem to input anything. Is there any better way to remap this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should never use `*map` when you can't answer why you are prefering it to `*noremap`. Command that does not fall into infinite recursion is

```
nnoremap d "_d
```

By the way, yank buffer is `0`, not `"` which is the default for pasting. While `d` overrides `"`, it does not do so to `0`. `y` though overrides both `"` and `0`.

Comment: Thanks, nnoremap works. Now it seems obvious why it was failing (the last d was being infinitely remapped).